# Suggestion installing receptacles on basement wall?

Tags: electrical, receptacle, code-compliance

I plan to install four 20 amp duplex receptacles on a basement concrete wall in area marked by red rectangle (see picture). Along the top of wall is a plumbing drain pipe.

Suggestions for installing the receptacles in this area that are compliant with code? The breaker box is about 15' away on an opposite wall.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Surface mount boxes and conduit are the usual. I don't believe you'd have to run conduit all the way back to the box if you terminate it properly.

You could also hang 2x4 lumber from the ceiling joists as a pseudo-wall, or simply plywood and attach wire and boxes to that.

Comment: If you do not run conduit, the wire should be 'concealed' which simply means it can't be run on the surface of building material. If you don't want to use conduit you should fir out at least a standard 3.5" stud wall on the surface of the concrete to hang the wiring on. A 2x2 stud is not considered adequate anymore. Once the wiring is up in the floor joist that is considered concealed/protected.